# Just installed vim-javacomplete2 but doesn autocomplete at all

Tags: java, vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I am newbie to plugins in vim. I am using vim for a year but without any experience with plugins. So i installed Vim-plug, then add `Plug vim-javacomplete2'` to my .vimrc and `:PlugInstall` it. It was installed. Then I add `autocmd FileType java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete` to my .vimrc as well - as is in github. But then, ther is nothing else. So some commands works. I Tried for example `JCgenerateAccessors` - which generate getter and setter upon my private fields. So commands works. But The autocompletation doesn (such main function). I am making classes within a file in my directory. Then `javac Test.java` and `java Test` - which runs it. But still, when editting in vim the `Test.java`, no autocompletation. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Might a a bit late

`<C-x><C-o>` (`ctrl + x`,`ctrl + o`) will bring up a list of options.

Press this in insert mode wherever you would press `ctrl + space` in other IDEs
i.e.: after `System.`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon @iaquobe's answer, autocompletion while typing or more specifically after the dot notation, isn't enabled by default with this plugin, unless triggered manually using <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, which can -and will- become tedious over time.

There're other autocompletion plugins that can be installed along with other completion engines, and be configured to integrate with them, namely: `vim-mucomplet`, `youcompleteme`, and `neocomplete.vim`.